# Problem in triggering GITLAB pipeline when changes to a file in external repository

Tags: gitlab, bitbucket, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I have GITLAB setup to pull repository from bitbucket.
I want pipeline to run automatically when there is pull request and  when there are changes in files.
But it seems to not work.

This is the rule I have setup in pipeline:

```
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "external_pull_request_event"
      changes:
        - Dockerfile
      when: manual
```

Kindly help to debug

Answer (score 0):

> I want pipeline to run automatically

Then the first thing to change would be to remove the [`when:manual`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#create-a-job-that-must-be-run-manually), which is used to require that a job *doesn’t* run unless a user starts it.

The combination you used (`rules`/`if`/`changes`/`when:manual`) was seen in the GitLab documentation at "[Complex rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#complex-rules)", but does not fit what you expressed in your question.